# Getting data from array of DataSet objects returned from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, dataset

I have a web service that I want to access when it is added as a web reference to my C# project.  A particular method in the web service takes a SQL query string and returns the results of the query as a custom type.  When I add the web service reference, the method shows up as returning `DataSet[]` instead of the custom type.  This is fine provided I can still somehow access the data returned from the query within those `DataSet` objects.  I ran a particular query that should return 6 rows; I got back a `DataSet[]` array with 6 elements.  However, when I iterate over those `DataSet` objects, none of them has any tables (via the  `Tables` property on the `DataSet`).  What gives?  Where is my data?

The web service is tested and works when I use it as a data source in a Report Builder 2.0 report.  I am able to send an XML SOAP query to the web service and get back XML results containing my data.

Here's a sample of how I'm getting the `DataSet[]` array:

```
var service = new MyWebService
    {
        Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    };
DataSet[] dataSets = service.MethodThatReturnsQueryResults(queryString);

// The body of this loop is skipped:
foreach (DataSet ds in dataSets.Where(ds => ds.Tables.Count > 0))
{
    // extract data from DataSet ds
}
```

**Edit:**  here is what the method looks like in the auto-generated Reference.cs that got created when I added the web reference:

```
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SomeCustomType")]
public System.Data.DataSet[] MethodThatReturnsQueryResults(
    string selectSQLQuery) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("MethodThatReturnsQueryResults", 
            new object[] { selectSQLQuery});
    return ((System.Data.DataSet[])(results[0]));
}
```

So it's definitely returning a `System.Data.DataSet[]`, but I wonder if something is happening such that the custom type used in the web service, `SomeCustomType`, is not getting translated correctly in that auto-generated method, hence the empty `DataSet` objects.  I'm hesitant to edit this auto-generated method.  I have access to the web service code; should I do something to it to ensure `SomeCustomType` can be cast to `DataSet[]`?

**Edit:** I feel like I could do better if I just got back the raw XML SOAP response from the web service.  How can I do this instead of getting the "translated" version that comes back as `DataSet[]`?

Comment: Have you verified they are Sysytem.Data.Dataset?

Comment: @Henk:  updated my question to show the return type of the web service method.

Comment: It might help if you post the (header of) the WebNethod on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the web service reference from my project and instead wrote a utility class for sending a SOAP request and getting the response back in XML, thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20011103.asp).  Here are a couple snippets:

```
public XmlDocument SendSoapRequest(XmlDocument soapRequest)
{
    var webRequest = getWebRequest();
    Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    soapRequest.Save(requestStream);
    requestStream.Close();
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    requestStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var soapResponse = new XmlDocument();
    soapResponse.Load(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(
        new StreamReader(requestStream).ReadToEnd()
    )));
    return soapResponse;
}

private HttpWebRequest getWebRequest()
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", SoapAction);
    webRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
    webRequest.Accept = AcceptHeader;
    webRequest.Method = RequestMethod;
    return webRequest;
}
```

I then use an XPath query to navigate the returned `XmlDocument` and get the data I want, the data that was *not* showing up in the `DataSet[]` that I got back from the web service when I used a web reference.  I already had a class that implements `IXmlSerializable` so once I navigate the returned XML with XPath, I just pass an `XmlReader` to my class's `ReadXml` method and the class instance gets populated.